# Sonicwall: cannot send email (outlook) and drops connection (google drive)

Tags: smtp, tcp, outlook, sonicwall

I will start by saying Im a web developer and my networking knowledge is very limited, please be patient =) . We dont have network/sysad in our company.

We are having problem with our connection. We cannot send outgoing email on our outlook UNLESS we restart the interface by pressing the `disconnect button` (see picture). After restarting, the emails will be sent BUT after few minutes same problem occurs, then we have to restart again! We are also using google drive is unable to connect to google server (not sure if its because of frequent restarts we are doing)

[image]

by the way, we had this problem solved (kinda) for a month or two, everything is working fine until I pressed the `disconnect button`. Then the problem starts occuring again until now.

`Please note that we dont have any problem receiving emails. Only for outgoing.`

We are using `Sonicwall Model TZ 105`

[image]

Other Info:

- Email Client: Outlook 2013/2016
- OS of Users: Windows 8/8.1/10
- Email Provider: Etisalat (local provider in United Arab Emirates)
- Outgoing Server: mailv.emirates.net.ae Port: 25
- Incoming Server: mailv.emirates.net.ae Port: 110
- SSL: we are not using it (not sure what to provide)

**Update**

When using cmd on host machine and try pinging the outgoing mail server Im having `request timeout` response. But when pinging inside virtual machine (virtualbox) Im receiving different response (see image). When using `mobile data` and ping the outgoing server `mailv.emirates.net.ae` using `host machine` then its successful. I've also tried different laptop and ping `mailv.emirates.net.ae` they are successful.

[image]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

If you need further information please let me know.

Comment: Where is your email hosted?  What ISP are you using?

Comment: Our email and ISP are hosted at Etisalat (local provider in United Arab Emirates)

Comment: Can you update your question with information about your Outlook settings such as server name, port, SSL/TLS, etc?

Comment: I put them on the other info section. Sorry if I can't provide other information, I dont know what and where to get the details.

Comment: Do you receive an error message when you try to send mail?  If so, please provide that error message in your question.

Comment: I suspect a node limit, for how many node the sonicwall is licensed ? Outgooing traffic will be blocked for nodes not licensed)

Comment: @yagmoth555 I reupload the screenshot for the sonicwall spec to include other info. Please see my edit. Its saying `Nodes/Users` is unlimited.

Answer (score 3):

Etisalat is blocking port 25 as part of their spam mitigation policy.

> Dear Customer,
>
> Thank you for contacting Etisalat Business Services Support Desk
>
> Kindly be informed that we have implemented spam mitigation policy on dynamic IP Internet services in order to avoid our IP pool getting blacklisted.
>
> Those customers who are sending SPAM / MASS mail will be identified by spam mitigation algorithms and their internet SMTP traffic will be blocked and will not be able to send mails using outlook or any mail client for next 1 hour.
>
> Our system will refresh the checks every one hour and will unblock the network if the spam/mass mailing is stopped.
>   Customer have to delete emails which is stuck on outbox and make sure to not to send spam/bulk mails in order to continue the service without any interruption.
>
> Regards,
>   Abdelrahman Siddig
>   Customer Care/Business Services
>   Tel: 8009111
>   Fax: +971 6 7481000
>   Email: 8009111@etisalat.ae

Comment: +1 for putting the actual message of Etisalat

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your WAN IP is getting, or is already, blacklisted.  This could be because you have a computer on your network that is sending out spam.  When you Disconnect and reconnect to PPPoE interface, you are given a new WAN IP address which is clear from any blacklists.  After a few minutes the computer on your network has been spamming out on the new WAN IP so the blacklists start picking up that IP address.

You can see evidence of this theory using the MX Toolbox Blacklist check:

http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a92.96.70.123

Another possibility is that the IP addresses you are being assigned from your ISP are already blocked.

To get around this problem, typically your ISP will have an Outgoing email server you can use.  For example, if your ISP is Comcast you can generally use smtp.comcast.net with the appropriate settings.

**Edit**
The error you're getting indicates that your ISP may be blocking you or having problems of their own.  You may want to reach out to them for help.

Comment: Yeah we also suspect that one before, now the problem is not occuring anymore. We just changed the TCP timeout to 1440 (12hrs) and MTU to 1484. But we are still unsure if thats the one solved the problem. We will try to check the tool you're suggesting. Thank you!

Comment: how to check if there's a computer spamming out emails?

Comment: Look for evidence of malware on each computer, such as slowness, pop ups, or strange errors.  Use antivirus to run a full scan on each computer.  Use a program like Malwarebytes to run a full scan.

Answer (score 0):

i have Symatec Endpoint protection and malwarebytes in all the PCs even though etisalat is blocking outlook outgoing mails. Seems etisalat consider all legitimate mails are SPAM !!! and they simply block port 25 for long time and it open after office hours.

Comment: yeah that's what I think as well, resetting the router to get a new dynamic IP will let you send couple of emails but then you'll get blocked again. we didn't encounter the same issue after getting a static IP.